# Setting up a GUI-based libvirt VM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am attempting to create a virtual machine using libvirt that will have a GNOME GUI and remote accessibility. I have successfully set up the VM to run, but I am unable to access it remotely.

The command issued to build the VM:

```
sudo vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --suite=precise --flavour=generic --arch=amd64 --mirror=http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu -o --libvirt=qemu:///system --part=/usr/xxxx/vmbuilder.partition --templates=/usr/xxxx/mytemplates --addpkg=nano --addpkg=unattended-upgrades --addpkg=acpid --firstboot=/usr/xxxx/boot.sh --cpus=2 --mem=4096--user=xxxx --name=xxxx --pass=xxxx --hostname=xxxx --bridge=br0
```

My intent is to have a virtual machine that my client can remotely access with a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use virt-manager package for KVM/QEMU virtual machine GUI management tool.

To know how to install it please follow the guide in [this post on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/141324/91632)